# Tkinter PhotoImage in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook. I have a problem in compounding a photo with a button in tkinter library.
I used PhotoImage function and I'v wrote the specific address of the photo I wanted to upload and compound with the button but each time I receive an error

`"TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "C:/Users/bcz/Desktop/ax.png/""`

I'v tried writing the address with \ and / and I'v tried different photos but the eror is the same.

```
master=Tk()
master.title('test')
lb=Button(master,text='click')
lb.pack()
lb.config(foreground='pink')
ax=PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/bcz/Desktop/ax.png/',master=master)
lb.config(image=ax,compound='down')
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why have you added the "jupyter-notebook" tag to the question? Are you using Jupyter? Jupyter is not well designed for operations that will open local windows on your machine. You should try to run your code local and use an IDE.

Comment: Yeah...you're right..I don't have the problem with shell window..

Comment: I am using jupyter because It doesn't need to install libraries such as numpy, pyplot,....

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the code on my machine and made minor changes.

```
from tkinter import *
master=Tk()
master.title('test')
lb=Button(master,text='click')
lb.pack()
lb.config(foreground='pink')
ax=PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/TFischer/Desktop/bird.png',master=master)
lb.config(image=ax,compound='center')
master.mainloop()
```

First: I deleted the las "/" right after "*.png". This is because the "/" signals another folder to be opend on a lower level.

Second: I changed `compound='down'` to `compound='center'` This was recomanded by my debugger since "down" is not permitted.

Comment: I just checked your code and the format of my photo is 'png'  but I received the error.                        'Couldn't recognize data in image file "C:/Users/bcz/Desktop/as.png" '

Comment: Can you check your code with another *.png image and share the code and error with us?